# Wordpress parent select need to be removed

Tags: pages, query, wp-editor, select

**Hi i have a Wordpress installation with over 35000 pages which are sorted into trees like so ...**
[image]

There is an ongoing issue with page edit loading very slowly or failing to load at all.
Through long trial and error and research i found it to be caused by the loading of parent select (10K pages crashes it)

on previous similar projects i disabled the parent select through the following function but it still seems to run a huge query causing it to run out of memory

```
add_filter( 'quick_edit_dropdown_pages_args', 'limit_parents_wpse_106164' );
add_filter( 'page_attributes_dropdown_pages_args', 'limit_parents_wpse_106164' );

function limit_parents_wpse_106164( $args ) {
  $args['child_of'] = 4009;
  //Id 4009 post dosn't exist
  return $args;
 }
```

is there a way to dequeue the Query from happening and removing parent select from page attribute section all together?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try the plugin [Nested Pages](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-nested-pages/), which replaces the native WP screen for pages (& optionally other post types) - it might be built to better handle them

Comment: I tested it earlier and not a possible solution as their ajax fails while loading the 35k+ pages. the ordering is not a problem as im using  CMS Tree Page View (https://wordpress.org/plugins/cms-tree-page-view/) View for ordering. what i really need is to prevent that query from executing

Comment: Does putting `$args['post_type'] = 'does_not_exist';` instead in the filter help at all?

Comment: @bonger that seem to have resolved the issue could you post as an answer and explain a bit and i will upvote and accept it. thank you

Comment: Excellent, I'll do that, ta...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per comments a way around it is to set the `post_type` to something that isn't a hierarchical type in the filter, as the `wp_dropdown_pages()` function used to populate the select calls `get_pages()` which just returns without doing anything if the `post_type` isn't hierarchical. So using a non-existent `post_type` works:

```
function limit_parents_wpse_106164( $args ) {
    $args['post_type'] = 'does_not_exist';
    return $args;
}
```

Note that the original filter idea comes from @brasofilo [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/106190/57034).